# How can I count visitor's views of specific block?

Tags: 7

I know I can use Statistics module to get total views for specific node.

**But how can I count visitor's views of specific block?**

The block is not connected to some fixed path (or node) and the block can be displayed in any place of site.
I could not find any module for the task.
What hook would be better to use to count visitor's views of the block?

Comment: [hook_block_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7.x)

Comment: AFAIK hook_block_view work only for custom block which created inside custom module. Still finding more universal solution.

Comment: It seems **hook_entity_view** can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function mymodule_entity_view($entity, $type, $view_mode, $langcode) {

    if ($type == 'node' &&  $entity->nid == 17457) {
        $entity->field_counter['und']['0')]['value']++;
        node_save($entity);
    }

}
```